# Redundant not_if?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am taking over a project and we are working with chef automation and im going over the recipe setup and I am confused with this:

```
not_if do
    existing_usernames = []
    Etc.passwd {|user| existing_usernames << user['name']}
    existing_usernames.include?(release_user)
  end
```

Does this not_if statement ever run? The file has other things that seem to not be in use commented out

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/Chef%2FResource:not_if

Comment: @emaillenin So itll only run if existing_usernames.include?(release_user) ?

Answer (score 0):

[`not_if` is a guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#attributes) for chef resource.

> `not_if`: Prevent a resource from executing when the condition returns true.

so for you question, yes - it runs before chef resource is executed.

Comment: So what would be an equivalent javascript or C# comparison of this statement?

Comment: @Cacoon: please read -- `not_if` is a guard for **chef resource**. it has nothing to do with neither javascript, not c#.

Comment: I know it is and I e read the chef doc on it but I’m still not clear if the code block I posted will run or not

Comment: @Cacoon: you are not reading :), so once again -- the chef resource will be executed only if the guard is evaluated to `true`.

Comment: But there’s nothing for the guard to check? I can understand not_if Boolean do